# Finding the Volume of Region in Three-Dimensional Space.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I am currently working on calculating the volume of the region $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, defined by the constraints:

$$W=\{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 ∣ z≥2,  x^2+y^2≤6−z,  y≥x \} .$$

My approach involves using triple integration, and the volume integral I have formulated is as follows:

$$V = \int_{2}^{4} \int_{x}^{\sqrt{6-x^2}} \int_{2}^{6-x^2-y^2} \, dz \, dy \, dx .$$

However, I find myself at a stage where I need assistance confirming if my approach is correct. Could you provide guidance on how to tackle this analytical development? Are there any suggestions for simplifying the integration or considerations I should be aware of?

I appreciate any help or insights you can offer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 \le 6-z$ intersects the plane $z=2$

$x^2+y^2 \le 4$ in a disk of radius 2.

The image of the region in the plane $z = 2$

[image]

If we want to integrate in cartesian coordinates, we are going to have to break up this integral into two regions.  That which is to the left of the line $x = -\sqrt 2$ and what is to the right of that line.

your integral should be:

$\int_{-2}^{-\sqrt 2} \int_{-\sqrt {6-x^2}}^{\sqrt {6-x^2}} \int_2^{\sqrt {6-x^2-y^2}} \ dz\ dy\ dx + \int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{x}^{-\sqrt {6-x^2}} \int_2^{\sqrt {6-x^2-y^2}} \ dz\ dy\ dx$

Rather than splitting this into two integrals, I would suggest you try one of two things.

1. We could rotate the coordinates 45 degrees.

$x = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} (u+v)\\y = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} (v-u)$

Solving for $u,v$
$u = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} (x+y)\\v = \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} (y-x)$

$y>x \implies v > 0$

$\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt {6-u^2}} \int_2^{\sqrt {6-u^2-v^2}} \ dz\ dv\ du $

You could probably just make the argument that this figure can be rotated without formally going through the coordinate conversion.

2. We could convert to polar.

$x = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin\theta\\
dy\ dx = r\ dr\ d\theta$

$\int_{\frac {\pi}{4}}^{\frac {5\pi}{4}}\int_0^2 \int_2^{6-r^2} r\ dz \ dr\ d\theta$

or you could do both.

$x = r\cos (\theta+\frac {\pi}{4})\\
y = r\sin(\theta+\frac {\pi}{4})\\
dy\ dx = r\ dr\ d\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_0^2 \int_2^{6-r^2} r\ dz \ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: $\int_{-2}^{-\sqrt 2} \int_{-\sqrt {6-x^2}}^{-\sqrt {6-x^2}} \int_2^{\sqrt {6-x^2-y^2}} \ dz\ dy\ dx$ I'm a bit puzzled by the integral with respect to y, which seems to have the same upper and lower limit. (I admit that I'm quite rusty when it comes to triple integrals, and I was following your answer step-by-step to shake off some of the rust :-) )

Comment: @Vorbis Sorry, it should be from $-\sqrt{6-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{6-x^2}$.  It has been fixed.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user317176 Thank you very much! I have a question: in this integral $\int_{\frac {\pi}{4}}^{\frac {5\pi}{4}}\int_0^2 \int_2^{6-r^2} r\ dz \ dr\ d\theta$  why is $\theta$ between ${\frac {\pi}{4}}$ to ${\frac {5\pi}{4}}$?

Comment: @Ayesca look at the picture.  Where is theta over the region.

Comment: @user317176 How absent-minded I've been! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you draw the $2$D domain you get half circle meaning that the volume described by $W$ is half a paraboloid with base at $z=2$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_W=\dfrac{V_{\text{paraboloid}}}{2}&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\int_2^6\int_0^{\sqrt{6-z}}\rho d\rho dz\\
&=\pi\int_2^6\left[\dfrac{\rho^2}{2}\right|_{0}^{\sqrt{6-z}}dz\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\int_2^6(6-z)dz=\dfrac{\pi}{2}[(36-18)-(12-2)]=4\pi\ \text{u}^2.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a question: why is $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ if $y \geq x$?

Comment: You could either compute the whole volume of the paraboloid and then divide by 2, or no dividing by 2 and evaluating from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/4+\pi$.